# Dynamic data in Datatable Jquery

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.3

I am using datatable in my Laravel project. and rendering values using foreach. While the page loads the data is rendered, but it shows an alert error message i have attached below.

[image]

Comment: do you have API for page 0 ?
I think that is the problem.

Comment: there is most likely something malformed in your json data structure coming back on the response.  Use developer tools (f12) to look at the json response and compare it to the DataTables spec

Comment: We also may be able to assist further if you post the json response that is getting sent to DataTables so we can review it

Answer (score 0):

From your controller, wrap the array of your result in a new array called data as below

```
return json_encode( array('data' => $your_result_array) );
```

which means your controller returns a json.
Then do this in your js

`$('#your_table_id').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: 'your_url_from_which_you_get_json_data',
      dataType: 'json'
    },
    columns: [
      { data: 'your_json_value_key', title: 'your_datatable_column_heading' },
      { data: 'your_json_value_key', title: 'your_datatable_column_heading' },
      { data: 'your_json_value_key', title: 'your_datatable_column_heading' },
      { data: 'your_json_value_key', title: 'your_datatable_column_heading' },
      { data: 'your_json_value_key', title: 'your_datatable_column_heading' },
      { data: 'your_json_value_key', title: 'your_datatable_column_heading' },
      //and so on ...
    ],
    destroy: true,
  });`

Drop a comment if it doesn't work for you, i will be glad to clarify